# How do i pass extra context from DRF Custom authentication class

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF for building an API in django. I have written a custom authentication class based on `rest_framework.authentication.BaseAuthentication`, that validates a incoming JWT. Within the JWT payload i have an attribute, say `"organisation_id":"123"`, which i would like to access in the view that processes the request. Is there any possibility to add the attribute to the context of the `request` object? According to the [DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication), the `authenticate` method of the `BaseAuthentication` should only return the tuple `(user, auth)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you already have the request as an argument to the authentication function. You should be able to add your organisation_id to the request:

```
request.organisation_id = organisation_id
```

This should do although I would personally rather go with adding it to the user.

Your call.

Comment: This worked. I share the same view as you. I found a way to bound that information to the request.user object. Much better! Thanks